# AS3 getting a List item index on a mouse roll over event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am trying to get the index of an item in a List object on a mouse roll over event (please keep in mind this is not the selectedIndex I need). Heres the code i am currently using:

```
list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, onItemRollOver);
function onItemRollOver(e:Event):void {
var itemInfo:Number = 0;

/*
    THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE INDEX NUMBER OF THE ITEM BEING ROLLED OVER INSTEAD OF THE SELECTED ITEM
*/
itemInfo = list.selectedIndex; 

txt_Display.text = 'Item Index #: ' + itemInfo;

play();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the event your listener function takes as a parameter.

This should work:

```
itemInfo = e.index;
```

Comment: Ya i thought thats what it should be but it compiles with an error if i put that code in i also tried ë.currentTarget.index; and it doesn't work either... Any other ideas?                          The error I get is: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property someProperty through a reference with static type flash.events:Event.

Comment: I just figure out why it gave that error in my function i had e:Event instead of e:ListEvent once I changed that and used e.index as you stated it began working fine! Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify heres the final code that works:

```
list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, onItemRollOver);
function onItemRollOver(e:ListEvent):void { 
var itemInfo:Number = 0;

itemInfo = e.index;

txt_Display.text = 'Item Index #: ' + itemInfo;

play();
}
```

Thanks again for the help!